# Apple cider vinegar in roasting pan

Tags: roasting, turkey, vinegar, smoking

I am smoking a turkey and don’t have broth to use in the base of the roasting pan. The turkey was brined over night.

I was thinking of putting the turkey on a bed of celery and carrots with 3 cups of water and 1 cup of [apple cider vinegar](http://bragg.com/products/bragg-organic-apple-cider-vinegar.html). Is this a good idea or is this too much vinegar?

Comment: I've never used vinegar like this personally, but that sounds like a high proportion of vinegar.  The moisture below poultry during smoking is mostly there just to keep high humidity anyway, and some people just use plain water. Again, I'm not posting as an answer because I haven't done this myself so I don't feel like I know for certain, but that much vinegar seems like it would (1) leave the celery and carrots with a somewhat "pickled" flavor and (2) might create a slightly sour taste in the outer layers of the turkey itself during smoking (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: If you're smoking the turkey, i wouldn't bother putting anything but water in a pan. Just seems like a waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any turkey, chicken, or vegetable stock or bouillon on hand, I would recommend using all water. That said, without stock or dissolved bouillon, your vegetables will not get the added extra flavor.

I would recommend adding a small amount of salt and/or other seasonings to the water so the vegetables won't be bland. E.g. of others, white or black pepper, poultry seasoning, garlic powder, or a spice blend like Mrs. Dash. Go light, as you can always add more later.

As others have commented, one cup is a huge amount of vinegar. And even a small amount of vinegar is likely to give the turkey an off taste and definitely will hurt the taste of the vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

Use purchased or homemade chicken stock in lieu of what liquids (water and or turkey stock) the recipe calls for.

Cider and other vinegars are likely to give the turkey an undesireable taste/flavor.

Comment: I agree that I would typically use homemade chicken stock (or even water), but why is the vinegar likely to give an undesirable flavor?

Comment: I understand using chicken stock rather than water. But why would you use chicken stock if a recipe calls for turkey stock and you have it on hand? I always use turkey stock with turkey.

Comment: The question clearly states the cook does NOT have turkey broth! - Cynetta